# Transforming a statistic and its standard error

Tags: statistics

Suppose for a statistic $X$ I compute a value $x$ and a standard error $\varepsilon$ on a given sample $S$. Is this set of information enough to compute $f(X)$ and its standard error ($f$ is a function like exponential) on $S$? For some practical reason, I can't compute $f(X)$ directly from the data in $S$. By the way, I'm not a mathematician.

Comment: Possibly helpful: [Variance of a function of one random variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5782/variance-of-a-function-of-one-random-variable) and [Approximating the expected value and variance of the function of a (continuous univariate) random variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/301861/approximating-the-expected-value-and-variance-of-the-function-of-a-continuous-u)